# +placemarkWithLocation method for CLPlacemark

Tags: objective-c, clplacemark

I want to use this method.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clplacemark/2132103-placemarkwithlocation?language=objc#declarations

I imported `CoreLocation` but I still get "No known class method" error and I also don't see it defined anywhere in `CLPlacemark.h`.

```
+ (instancetype)placemarkWithLocation:(CLLocation *)location 
                                 name:(NSString *)name 
                        postalAddress:(CNPostalAddress *)postalAddress;
```

Comment: Please post the code in which you actually call that method.

Comment: [CLPlacemark placemarkWithLocation:location name:name postalAddress:postalAddress];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation,

> App extensions built with the Intents framework can use this method to
>   create a placemark from existing location and address data. For
>   example, an app that offers a ride service might create a new
>   placemark when resolving a user’s pickup or drop-off location. The
>   returned placemark contains only the data that you provide.

So you need to import Intents framework:

```
@import Intents;
```